# How is the given determinant expanded into the two below?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am confused on how they expand the main determinant into the sum of the two below it. My first idea is that they use cofactor expansion with the columns, which is how they get the a0 coefficient in front of the second term in the sum, however neither determinant in the sum would be the resulting determinant when eliminating the given row and column. Furthermore, I do not see how the determinant on the right part of the sum turns out to be $(-1)^{k-1}$ in the line below it. Any pointers help!
[image: 1]

Comment: They do cofactor expansion along the top row.

Comment: This is a typo. In the second determinant with factor $a_0$ there should be $-1$ on all entries for the main diagonal instead of $t$.